# Print Inverted Half Pyramid

Tags: java, design-patterns

Print inverted half pyramid as shown:

```
1111
222
33
4
```

My code is:

```java
public class HW5 {
    //5.   Print Inverted Half Pyramid.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 4;
        for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Above code gives following output:

```
4444
333
22
1
```

How do I print the required output as shown above?

Comment: what changes have you made in an attempt to get the other result?

Comment: You need a function which will map 4 -> 1, 3, -> 2, ... 1-> 4. Can you think of an expression which does that?

Comment: Simply change your print statement to: `System.out.print(n-i+1);`

Comment: BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character

Comment: Thanks @Jens .. and i will take care of java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap the `for` loops. The outer loop is the number to print and the inner loop is the number of times to print it.

```java
public class HW5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 4;
        for (int j = 1; j <= n ; j++ ) {
            for (int i = n - j + 1; i >= 1; i--) {
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Above code gives following output:

```
1111
222
33
4
```